# How do I map a domain to a Monero address via OpenAlias.org?

Tags: openalias

I've seen people talk about connecting their Monero addresses to a domain (eg, xmr.domain.com), because a domain is a lot easier to remember than a 95-character Monero address.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, for the readers. An explanation of what OpenAlias precisely is and how it works can be found [here](https://openalias.org/index.html). Now to your question, this is done as follows. First, access your domain name configuration page. Note that it isn't possible to create an OpenAlias entry with merely an email address. Thus, if you don't have a domain, you have to buy one. At [Gandi](https://www.gandi.net/), for example, you are able to buy domains. Second, you should edit your DNS zone. Note that if you are using cPanel it can be found under "Advanced DNS Zone Editor". The URL ends with `zoneedit/advanced.html`. Lastly, the following data should be entered:

**Name:** Your domain name or sub-domain name (which should end with a period)

**TTL:** 14400 (or the same TTL as you other entries; it doesn't really matter)

**Type:** TXT

**TXT Data:** `oa1:xmr recipient_address=address; recipient_name=Your name\; tx_description=Your description\;`

Note the escaping backslashes before the semi-colon. You can include a space in the "recipient_name" and "tx_description" entries.

An example of how it should look like is as follows:

**Name:** donate.getmonero.org.

**TTL:** 14400

**Type:** TXT

**TXT Data:** `oa1:xmr recipient_address=44AFFq5kSiGBoZ4NMDwYtN18obc8AemS33DBLWs3H7otXft3XjrpDtQGv7SqSsaBYBb98uNbr2VBBEt7f2wfn3RVGQBEP3A; recipient_name=Monero Development Fund\; tx_description=Donation to development\;`

---

For Gandi the instructions are as follows. You should access the web interface for editing the DNS Zone file and add the following:

`@ 14400 IN TXT "oa1:xmr recipient_address=address; recipient_name=Your name\; tx_description=Your description\;"`

**Source:** https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/2uv214/what_is_openalias/

Comment: So the first semicolon shouldn't be escaped?

Comment: As far as I know, no.

Comment: FYI: It is escaped on the donate.getmonero.org domain: `$ dig -t TXT donate.getmonero.org` returns `oa1:xmr recipient_address=44AFFq5kSiGBoZ4NMDwYtN18obc8AemS33DBLWs3H7otXft3XjrpDtQGv7SqSsaBYBb98uNbr2VBBEt7f2wfn3RVGQBEP3A\; recipient_name=Monero Development\; tx_description=Donation to Monero Core Team\;`.