# How can I receive monero on my openalias address?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, openalias

I've amended my domain records by following [this procedure](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1365/1061) and my new [OpenAlias](https://openalias.org/) address is `xmr.mysite.com.`.

How could someone transfer Moneroj to me using that alias? Can it be done using monero-wallet-cli?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type:

`transfer xmr.mysite.com 0.50`

You will get a prompt asking you to confirm the full address and show a DNSSEC validation notice. If it is okay, enter `Y`

Comment: I hadn't realised it was that simple.